# want to show the thickness of an element while it rotate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, rotation, css-transitions

I am rotating a coin along Y axis by 90deg through CSS. Is there a way so that I can show the thickness of the coin after it have rotated, I thought I can scaleY after the coin have rotated along Y axis but this doesn't seem to work. Please suggest some way to do the same if it is possible. [link_on_js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EtLu/) for the same. Please use webkit browsers to open the link.

**css**

```
.coin {
    display: block;
    background: url("url-to-image-of-coin.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}

.flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="coin"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.coin').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flip');
});
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/7EtLu/22/

Comment: What do you mean with "thickness of the coin"? It is just 2D, there is no real z-axis existing.

Comment: as i am using a 2-D image for the coin but actually a coin is a 3-D object so when I should rotate it along Y axis I should see the thickness as well to have realistic effect. Can this be done with css itself ??

Comment: Ah okay. I think CSS can't fit your requirements. This looks like a task for Canvas. But I have no experience with it.

Comment: ok even i don't, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements to give an effect that is similar. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/y7rQL/

```
<div class="coin"></div>
```

```
body {
    transform: perspective(500px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.coin {
    background-image: url("http://www.coolemails4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/indian_rupee.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100px;
}
.coin:after {
    background-color: #262626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    width: 5px;
    z-index: -10;
}
.coin:before {
    background-color: #262626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateZ(-5px);
    width: 100px;
}
.coin:hover {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}​
```

Also, here is a version that spins 180 degrees (it isn't quite as nice though): http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/Bz22S/

Comment: @joshnh thanks a lot your reply really helped :) ..... really awesome how u did it ....

Comment: @joshnh I tried to use your approach in my large code, my coin div in a large tree of other divs. It seems that Preserve-3d property is not working can you suggest me what are various scenarios where preserve-3d is not maintained and -webkit-transition-style is just set to flat instead.please help

Comment: Hmm, strange. Might be worth asking another question for? It's a little hard to know what is happening without further information.

Comment: Very nice indeed. Have you had any luck getting it to work in IE11 though? http://jsfiddle.net/y7rQL/154/

Comment: Hello there, here's a fixed version of 180deg+ spin that looks as good as 90deg one. http://jsfiddle.net/t8gberzy/1/
I was unable to translateZ pseudo element inside translateZ'd parent for some reason, so layout not as slim, but it works and looks pretty good nevertheless.

Comment: Some explanation: `::before` is the back-face of the coin, while `::after` simulates the edge of the coin. The trick is noticeable when you significantly slow down the transition.

Comment: What part of the code is it that adds the depth? That's what i'm struggling to visualize...

Comment: @Bogomip It's ".coin:after" with the 5px width and the 90deg transform.

Answer (score 1):

@joshnh Thanks for the inspiration provided, here is a little modification to make it look more like:

```
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front"></div>
      <div class="flip-card-thick"></div>
      <div class="flip-card-back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent url(https://i.imgur.com/GPCt3mC.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: transform 4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back, .flip-card-inner:before, .flip-card-inner:after  {
  background-color: #a37131;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flip-card-inner:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
}

.flip-card-inner:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(10px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #a37131;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(11px);
}

.flip-card-thick {
  background-color: #a37131;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.25), hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
  bottom: 0;
  left: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 10px;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/solhuang/pen/QWqQNPP)