# Thickness when giving an flip effect in css javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I want to give thickness effect when the image flips and another image occurs. I want to give it thickness to look like a coin. Here is a link where some one has tried something similar but i am not able to integrate in my code.

```js
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('mapButtons')) {

                if (document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'none';
     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'block';     
                }
            }
}

function flip() {
    $('.side').toggleClass('rotated');
}
```

```css
#modelButtons {
  display: none;
}
.block {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-perspective:100%;
    -moz-perspective:100%;
    -ms-perspective:100%;
    -o-perspective:100%;
    perspective:100%;  
 
  }
.side {
 position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.side.rotated {

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
#flip-button,button {
width: 98px;
 height: 70px;
    background: white;
 border:none;
 outline:none;
   cursor: pointer; /* hand-shaped cursor */
 cursor: hand; /* for IE 5.x */
    border: 0;
 } 
.changeButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.changeButton:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}
.prevButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.prevButton:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}
.nextButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nextButton:hover img {
opacity: .3;
}
.notbutton{
 cursor: pointer; /* hand-shaped cursor */
 cursor: hand; /* for IE 5.x */
}
#mapButtons{
clear: left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="front side">
<svg name="map" id="map" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 453 453" pointer-events="fill" fill="none">
<image id="image" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/SY5h8EC.png?1" width="453" height="453"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="back side">
<svg name="map2" id="map2" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 453 453" pointer-events="fill" fill="none">
<image id="image1" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/eXFm7xH.png" width="453" height="453"/>
</svg>
</div>
</div>  

<div id = "mapButtons" >
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip(); switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/xQI1YEb.png"></button>
</div> 
<div id = "modelButtons" >
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip(); switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/EDjVcP4.png"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate here is the link.

Comment: I think you missred the post. Your round diagram should be a div, with a background image and a specific class, like `.diagram`. And I think the key is to use `.diagram:before` and `.diagram:after`

Comment: I am also using my diagram for navigation, using image map. So i cannot make it background image.