# How to make the div not dissapear when rotateY(90deg)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage I have a div. On that div I have "animation" that simulates the div being turned over (flipped).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

I rotate the "wrapper" div with the [jQuery plugin transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). What the plugin does is just apply the CSS;

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

When the div is on `rotateY(90deg)`, I have to load some new content in the `#content` div. This takes a minuscule amount of time, but in the animation you can see that the div is gone/hidden fore that time.

[SEE DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/39gahx7s/1/)
(note that I don't have the actual content loading in here)

Is it possible to have the dive not totally disappearing when `rotateY(90)`?

Unfortunately I have no control over the HTML itself because it is being generated.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a (not) working example? As far as I understand the problem, it is the loading/change and not the rotation.

Comment: Use two divs - so the content is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add thickness to it. Refer to something like this: [want to show the thickness of an element while it rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate)

But make the animation of the css:
    0%: transform: rotateY(0deg);
    50%:transform: rotateY(90deg);
    100%:transform: rotateY(180deg);

Hope this helps.

Make sure the jQuery plugin has css files or look into it.

And also you could do this using basic css and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the contents of the div, just create two sides:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="side-a">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div class="side-b">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    transition: all 2s;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper.flip{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.side-a{
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    transition-delay: 1s; //half the transition time of the wrapper
}
.side-b{
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.flip side-a{
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.flip side-b{
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.next-slide').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').addClass('flip');
});
$('.prev-slide').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper').removeClass('flip');
});
```

Comment: I don't think the plugin would be necessary