# Animate flip of SVG horizontally, but maintain path/stroke's width or thickness

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a flip of an SVG horizontally using the following:

```
.animated {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes customAnimation {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    right: 3px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    right: -172px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}

.customAnimation {
  animation-name: customAnimation;
}
```

Where the element I'm trying to rotate receives both `.customAnimation` and `animated` as classes when I want the flip to begin.

The problem is that at the animation's halfway point, the element is essentially a straight line. Ideally, it should maintain some amount of thickness/weight so that it looks more 3D. I've added a snippet to demonstrate: **(if you have issues running the snippet, the corresponding codepen is included below)** [click lock's circle to begin]

```js
$(".lock-circle").on("click", function(e){
    var $this = $(".lock-top");
    if($this.hasClass("animated")){
        $this.removeClass("animated");
        $this.removeClass("customAnimation");
    }else{
        $this.addClass("animated customAnimation");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.container { 
  width: 300px; 
  min-height: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FF9B02;
  
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}


svg { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.lock-top, .lock-circle { 
  width: 80%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lock-top { top: 0; right: 3px }
.lock-circle { top: -90px; }

/*******************************
 *          Animation
 ****************************/

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes customAnimation {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    right: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    right: -172px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}

@keyframes customAnimation {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    right: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    right: -172px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}

.customAnimation {
  -webkit-animation-name: customAnimation;
          animation-name: customAnimation;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
  <svg class="lock-top" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 111 114" style="enable-background:new 0 0 111 114;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: #FFFFFF;
      }
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M100,67.7c-0.3-23.8-19.6-43-43.5-43S13.3,43.9,13,67.7h0v13h8V68.2c0-19.6,15.9-35.5,35.5-35.5
      S92,48.6,92,68.2v22.5h8L100,67.7L100,67.7z" />
  </svg>

  <svg class="lock-circle" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 111 114" style="enable-background:new 0 0 111 114;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: #FFFFFF;
      }
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M98.5,25.7v-15h-8v6.2c-9.3-8.2-21.6-13.2-35-13.2c-29.3,0-53,23.7-53,53c0,29.3,23.7,53,53,53s53-23.7,53-53
      C108.5,45.1,104.8,34.4,98.5,25.7z M55.5,97.7c-22.6,0-41-18.4-41-41c0-22.6,18.4-41,41-41c22.6,0,41,18.4,41,41
      C96.5,79.3,78.1,97.7,55.5,97.7z M55.5,20.7c-19.9,0-36,16.1-36,36c0,19.9,16.1,36,36,36c19.9,0,36-16.1,36-36
      C91.5,36.8,75.4,20.7,55.5,20.7 M60,59.6c0,0,2.8,11.5,0.3,14c-1.7,1.7-7.9,1.7-9.6,0c-2.5-2.5,0.3-14,0.3-14
      c-1.9-1.4-3.1-3.5-3.1-6c0-4.2,3.4-7.6,7.6-7.6c4.2,0,7.6,3.4,7.6,7.6C63.1,56.1,61.8,58.3,60,59.6" />
  </svg>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/csengineer13/pen/JRdJjX

**Edit:** Suggested solution uses z-index and a series of layers to add depth to the rotating object. It essentially creates two new shapes that provide depth and an edge that are visible as the rotation occurs. The issue is that the solution is for a simple shape; a circle, and does not work for more complex SVG shapes.

Here is the example solution applied to this question:

http://codepen.io/csengineer13/pen/qadQXR

Doesn't resolve/fix; and I am doubtful that it can be modified to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want to show the thickness of an element while it rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate)

Comment: There is an answer in the question I marked as "duplicate" where he uses an `::after` pseudo-element that is pre-rotated, so that when everything else rotates "flat" that element is standing up and giving the appearance of height

Comment: Hmm.. I'm having some issues replicating this solution. In principle, it makes sense, but for whatever reason I can't duplicate the effect with my SVG.

I'll continue to play around and report back. I'll accept the "duplicate solution" suggestion if I can get the solution to work.

Comment: you could use vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke to maintain line's width.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I saw a similar question that mentioned adding that attribute to the SVG to accomplish the effect I want; however, I can't seem to get it to render/work. I think it could be due to using a "path" in the SVG instead of a different tag with a set line width.

Comment: It will work on a path too, provided you're using the stroke property of the path to display a line.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I don't believe this is my current case. I think I may need to convert my SVG to one that is more "developer friendly" so I can preserve that stroke width

Comment: In order for non-scaling-stroke to work, you will need to do two things: (1) convert your lock loop path to a single stroke path, not a path that describes the circumference (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGQNJm), and (2) apply your animated transform to just the path element, not the whole SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, beautiful. I was able to use your updated SVG path and some revised animation logic to get a working final copy: http://codepen.io/csengineer13/pen/JRYXPZ -- Thanks for your help. If you or RobertLongsdon want to write a more formal answer, I'd be more than happy to accept; If not, I'll throw up one in a day or so