# Is there a way to give elements thickness in CSS?

Tags: css, transform

Say for example I have a photo and I have a transform animation on it so it is rotating infinitely along the Y axis. When the photo reaches 90 degrees of rotation it disappears the reappears after 90 degrees. Is there some way to give it thickness or depth so rather than being like a rotating piece of paper it's like a thick rotating piece of card?

Comment: so it's a cube-like what you want .. So you need to create each side alone and adjust the rotation to have the needed effect

Comment: Can you put a 1-pixel line behind it?

Comment: This question seems to have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this can be done with CSS - It's something I've thought of before but is really the limits of my knowledge right now.

Comment: Andrew Morton. Do you mean like on the Z axis or something?

Comment: @MarkSLCarlyon I was thinking that if the photo disappears then the 1-pixel line will become visible and appear to be the thickness of the photo.

Comment: AndrewMorton - I understand the concept. I just am not 100% sure how to achieve this in the code.