# isometric calculations to rotate a cylinder (coin)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, isometric

I am attempting to make a rotating cylinder (a coin) in vanilla CSS (or JS if it isn't possible). I can do this fine for a side view but I am attempting to do this in an 'isometric' view.

I know how to create an isometric view for things that sit on 'normal' planes (vertical, horizontal or 'floor') via transforms.

I can also work out how to rotate cubes etc. with a few tricks with `skew`.

However I have got stuck attempting to rotate a cylinder. I am guessing it is due to the fact that the furthest part from the centre transforms differently than parts closer to the centre of the axis of rotation.

Below is a CSS only rotating coin (almost, couple of minor bugs but you get the idea) but I have a feeling I would need to scrap this and start again to get the visible top portion and the rotation correct.

What is the correct way to handle angles that aren't straight forward to get the correct perspective?

I am also happy with a pure JS solution using `canvas` if this cannot be achieved with CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: #353535;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.coin-holder{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.coin {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  animation: spin 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.coin .front, .coin .back {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.coin .front {
  transform: translateZ(25px);
}
.coin .back {
  transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.coin .side {
  transform: translateX(100px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.coin .side .circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.coin .side .circle:before, .coin .side .circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(84.375deg);
  background: #999900;
}
.coin .side .circle:before {
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.coin .side .circle:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(1) {
  transform: transform: skewY(30deg);rotateY(90deg) rotateX(11.25deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(22.5deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(33.75deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(56.25deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(67.5deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(78.75deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(101.25deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(112.5deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(123.75deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(135deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(146.25deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(14) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(157.5deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(15) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(168.75deg);
}
.coin .side .circle:nth-child(16) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(180deg);
}
.coin .front {
  background: yellow;
}
.coin .back {
  background: yellow;
}
.coin .front, .coin .back {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.coin .front:before, .coin .back:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  height: 250%;
  width: 30%;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  animation: shine 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  30% {
    left: 500px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) skewY(10deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateY(270deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
}
#gradient {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black, transparent, transparent);
  animation: scale 2.5s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  filter: url(#blur);
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(0.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow:column; align-items:center">
<div class="coin-holder">

  <div class="coin">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="side">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="gradient"></div>
  
  <svg style="display:none">
    <filter id="blur" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <!-- filter operations here -->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5">
      </feGaussianBlur></filter>
  </svg>
</div>
```

As requested an isometric coin looks like the following (static image) - obviously showing a rotating coin isn't possible otherwise I would know how to do it!

I am attempting to rotate around the y-axis.

[Here is a link to an image](https://www.dreamstime.com/vector-perspective-animation-sequence-isometric-gold-coin-rotate-sprite-sheet-coin-rotate-sprite-sheet-image111374338) showing different angles of rotation (I did not want to upload an image without a license)

Below is an image example from one angle.

[image: isometric coin example from one angle]

Comment: Any image that might provide a hint on exactly how you want the coin to look like?

Comment: The problem with that is that a static image of an isometric coin will not help as every angle would be different, I have added an image for illustration of what an isometric coin looks like on a 'normal' angle but it is impossible to show it at all angles while it rotates.

Comment: isometric is basically x axis at 30deg, z axis at 30deg and y axis as normal.

Comment: This is a tough one. Maybe you should consider using something like Three.js?

Comment: Something along these lines: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/BaNWKYX?editors=0110

Comment: Thanks for that bud, I think I confused the axis as I meant rotate around the vertical (always different ways of labelling depending on who you talk to :-P) I don't think we could go the Three.js route but I will consider it, we have very tight page weight budgets. However from a learning perspective that is awesome. Could you explain how to change the rotation to around the vertical axis and which bits control the perspective. If we can fall back to Three.js then that is a fantastic start you gave there!

Comment: nevermind I worked out how to change the axis but then I can't set the angles to look isometric, will have to look at the docs.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m7gh6t8L/ ok so that looks isometric enough, now if I can just work out which parts of three.js are relevant I might be able to strip out all the bits I don't need. Final question, how can I apply a texture to the coin? Just point me in the right direction, you have done plenty for me :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208523/discussion-between-kostasx-and-graham-ritchie).

Comment: [There is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate), for a simpler case (single axis rotation). Might be possible to use the same trick here, if your rotation is constrained enough (should be if you are really doing iso)

Comment: yeah, I can do the side view, isometric is where the maths becomes complicated as you can't just use a single transform. Thanks for the example though, provides an alternative using an image if I can think of a method for doing that in an isometric view!