# Struggling to add 3D effect to 2D css image rotation

Tags: html, css

I'm a very beginner in coding. I have a nail buffer that is spinning via css and I'm trying to make it appear that this nail buffer has depth when it is spinning.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/o6mugy8p/) is a JSfiddle showing the buffer rotation without any depth. It just looks thin like a piece of paper.

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644993/want-to-show-the-thickness-of-an-element-while-it-rotate) article to add the 3D depth effect to my rotation, but I cannot seem to implement it correctly into my code to get it to work... I have been looking at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8gberzy/1/) to model it after.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9rge8u/) is a JSFiddle of my attempt trying to implement the 3D depth code from the original article into my code, but it seems to not be working. I'm not sure how to correctly implement the solution into my much more confusing code.

Does anyone know how to accurately implement the psuedo route from the original article into my code / know where I am going wrong?

This is the additional code I've been trying to add to my original code to add the depth -

```
.deckcard3 .back:after,
.deckcard3 .front:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.deckcard3 .back {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.deckcard3 .front {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```